# event sourcing - handle batch transactions

Tags: c#, .net-core, projection, event-sourcing

I would like to implement event sourcing to an existing web application that I have. My implementation is a .NET Core WEB API, but that shouldn't matter. The web app imports a CSV file that contains bank account transactions (similar to an export from your bank account) to an API.

The API gets all of the transactions, validates them, and removes any that have been previously imported, then stores them into a transaction table. Reports are then generated from this data, such as, Total gas purchased last month, total amount spent on dining out in 2017, etc.

It seems to me that this type of application is ideal for event sourcing (or vice versa), but I am having a hard time understanding how to implement it. I am trying to implement something like [this simple example](https://github.com/cberthold/BankAggregate). It has an account aggregate that has transaction events, similar to what I'd like to do.

My first question is, how do I handle for batch transactions, where not all of them are saved, since some may be duplicates? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143589/transaction-handling-in-event-sourcing) does touch that subject, but this is different in that in some cases no transactions may be saved after the duplicate check since the file may be the same, or there just were not new transactions since the last import.

Second, how would I check if a transaction is a duplicate? Currently, my duplicate check looks like this:

```
        var all = await _transactionRepository.GetAll(-1);
        var lookup = all.ToLookup(x => Tuple.Create(x.PostingDate, x.Description, x.Amount, x.Balance));

        foreach (var o in original)
        {
            o.Created = DateTime.Now;

            if (!lookup.Contains(Tuple.Create(o.PostingDate, o.Description, o.Amount, o.Balance)))
            {
                // does not currently exist in the db so add to clean list
                final.Add(o);
            }
        }
```

Would I create a projection, looking for that specific event? I am having trouble understanding how to check for existing data.

Thanks in advance for any help understanding this.

Comment: "Would I create a projection, looking for that specific event? " -- making your logic to depend on a state of a projection is a good way to ruin your event sourcing. More fun could be found at https://leanpub.com/esversioning

Comment: That's my understanding of a projection. What is wrong with that thinking?

Comment: When requirements change (e.g. the way it should be decided if transaction is a duplicate or not), related projections also change, and this almost certainly will make it not possible to replay the events with the same result

Answer (score 0):

Where are your aggregate boundaries in this case? I think you have an individual Transaction aggregate, and not just a Batch aggregate, but it is not clear from your case. If you do have a Transaction aggregate, how do you derive the identity (i.e Aggregate Key) of the Transaction aggregate? Do you just generate a Guid?

You have a Tuple which represents the unique ID of the Transaction. From these values, you should be able to create a unique and reproducible ID, perhaps a hash. When you issue a "Create" command to that Transaction ID, and if the Transaction already exists, the operation should be idempotent and so therefore should do nothing. To guard against possible duplicate IDs, you can also check in your aggregate whether the details (e.g. PostingDate, Description, Amount...) match those in the Create command. If they do, then ignore the command. If they don't then emit a "CreateFailed" event to indicate a duplicate ID was generated. You can listen for that event in a Saga and then generate a new, but still reproducible ID and issue the Create command to that.

In this way, you are not dependent on projections which are eventually consistent , and subject to change, and are therefore not reliable.

Comment: Sorry put this aside for a long while and getting back to it. I have an Account Aggregate, similar to the example I linked above. I'd like to treat it the same way the example does, that treats each transaction individually, even though it comes in batches. It seems ideal for event sourcing. I had not considered the Transaction being an aggregate, since it feels more like an event.

Comment: I also don't see how I am dependent on projections by my question. I get that from your comment: "In this way, you are not dependent on projections which are eventually consistent..."